# monotonic mapping from $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

I'm looking for a monotonic mapping from $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$. The ones I can think of are $e^{x}$ and $\log(1+e^x)$, however they both seem to grow exponentially at the left hand side of the output range (say from 0 to 1).

Is there a monotonic (preferably differentiable) mapping that grows at a lower level initially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $f(x) = x + \sqrt{x^2+1}$.

Comment: This can be computed is a fairly stable way (numerically), but you would need a conditional.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=-1/x$ for $x\leq-1$ and $x+2$ for $x>-1$ seems to be OK.

Comment: thanks for the answer, what if I want the function to be differentiable?

Comment: The given function is differentiable.

Comment: ah, right, maybe I'm asking for too much, could you think of one that is not piecewise (so that I can implement it without using the `if` statement in a programming language)? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x) = (k\sin x)^2$ for $x\in[2k\pi, 2(k+1)\pi]$, $k$ an integer.